# Match a string using some regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I've a string that looks like this:

```
089 / 23249841noch not deposited
```

and I want to extract the following portion from the string:

```
089 / 23249841
```

How can I do this using PHP and regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to match everything before the first letter,

```
preg_match("/(^[^a-z]+)/i", "089 / 23249841noch not deposited", $match)
```

`$match` would then contain,

```
Array
(
    [0] => 089 / 23249841
    [1] => 089 / 23249841
)
```

Comment: You are welcome @MubinKhalid, glad it worked as you wanted it to :)

Answer (score 0):

With only one example, it's a little tricky to write a proper regex for that. However, this one should work:

```
[0-9 /]+
```

Or, in full PHP code:

```
$str = '089 / 23249841noch not deposited';
$matches = array();
if (preg_match('[0-9 /]+', $str, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches);
}
```